# WSO2 Identity Server Upgrade 5.0.0 -> 5.1.0 isCascadeDeleteEnabled in user-mgt.xml

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Referring to the [upgrade documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Upgrading+from+a+Previous+Release) the user-mgt.xml has a new property

```
<Property name="isCascadeDeleteEnabled">true</Property>
```

In case of an upgrade the documentation says:

> If you are connecting the database from a previous version of IS, set
>   this property to "false".

My question: Does this mean that an upgraded installation has a different setting as an installation from scratch?   Why that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This setting has been introduced in Carbon 4.4.2 in order to allow cascade delete in `UM_USER_PERMISSION`, `UM_ROLE_PERMISSION` tables when a permission get deleted form `UM_PERMISSION` [1].

When this property is set to `true`, a single query will be sent to parent table (UM_PERMISSION) so the respective rows from the child tables will be deleted automatically.

When this property is set to `false`, multiple queries will be sent first to child tables and then the parent table to delete the respective rows.

This database level `CASCADE DELETE` relationship is introduced in Carbon 4.4.2 databases. So this database level relationship is not available in the IS 5.0.0 database, therefore if you are using the same database with IS 5.1.0 you need to set the `isCascadeDeleteEnabled`property to `false`.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon443/Database+Upgrade+Guide

Comment: Thanks Lasantha for the detailed explanation. I just wonder what happens with a 5.0.0 system that gets upgraded to 5.1.0. Should the isCascadeDeleteEnabled set to true after successfully upgrading? I've thought the upgrade scripts would convert the database. Am I wrong?

Comment: You need to set the `isCascadeDeleteEnabled` to `false`, if you are using the **same user database** (without migrating). But if you are running the upgrade scripts to convert the database above `CASCADE  DELETE` constraint will be added. So you can keep the `isCascadeDeleteEnabled` as `true`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification